# Updates to Salesforce's CSS not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I have a lightning web component and on it I have

```
<lightning-input-field 
    field-name="Resource__c" 
    onchange={onResourceSelection} 
    data-lookup-id="temResourceLookup"
    value={resourceRecId}
    variant="label-hidden">
</lightning-input-field>
```

I want to change some of the styling so on the input and so I have this on the css portion of the component.

```
.slds-input:focus, .slds-input:active {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

Nothing changes.  Does anyone know what I need to do to get the style to use the CSS I have supplied?

Answer (score 2):

As input element of `lightning-input-field` gets generated dynamically and because of **shadow dom concept** you cannot reach that input element via lwc css file.
This can be achieved by loading a separate css class via `loadStyle` api

Create a zip folder `activeClassZip`
and add a css file to it `activeClassCSSFile.css`

Now the css file should have only this :

```
/* activeClassCSS */
.activeClass .slds-input:focus{
    outline: 0;
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

Now in your custom component js, just load this css file via:

```
import {loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'
import activeClassZip from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/activeClassZip'

renderedCallback() {

    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, activeClassZip + '/activeClassCSSFile.css')
    ])
}
```

and add this class in your html like this:

```
    <lightning-input-field class="activeClass" field-name={Email} variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
```

Comment: Be aware that, at some point in time, this trick will stop working. Right now, we only have faux shadow DOM, but the real thing won't allow tricks like this.

Comment: But is there an official way to override the css, of this gets stopped.  I mean we have done this in lot of places. Also used aura to load css separately to override some of lwc and aura components css and also hide some standard buttons. Will aura loading css be also stopped?

Comment: SLDS Hooks should solve this once it’s ready!

Comment: @NagendraSingh There will be an official path at some day, but be aware that this is not the path. At least, you should document your usage of this trick.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the info and yes we are maintaining a documentation of all the external tricks we have applied.

Comment: @sfdcfox there's another trick,if we wrap LWC with Aura and modify the css for slds classes in the Aura component, we can achieve this, I just want to confirm whether that one will also stop working?
I guess the final implementation of shadow DOM will not allow.

Comment: @PrashantKashyap Correct. Again, I expect we'll have some path forward, but it won't be as simple as wrapping in an Aura component and overriding. These are all things that only work with the faux Shadow DOM we have today.

Comment: Thanks for the update, we are just going through implementation and will keep these things in mind.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the example given on the styling hooks Doc work with just a button on the page and the CSS as given in the doc example. It is not working for me and throws error.  CssSyntaxError: LWC1009: postcss-plugin-lwc: 6:5: Invalid definition of custom property "--sds-c-button-brand-color-border".    I think I will give up for couple of months and entertain style requests from business when these stabilize.

Answer (score 2):

As `@Mohith` mentioned `Styling hooks` are the official way. You can achieve the same with

```
.slds-input:active{
    --lwc-colorBorderInputActive: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    --lwc-colorBackgroundInputActive: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    --lwc-shadowButtonFocus: 0 0 5px rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

Also, Styling hooks are still in beta so maybe there could be changes to the property conventions. Read more able [SLDS Hooks here.](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/)