# How to increase height of <lightning-input

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

how to increase the height of the

```
              <lightning-input
                class="customInput"
                  type="url"
                  label="URL"
                  value={url}
                  variant="label-hidden"
                  onchange={handleUrl}
                ></lightning-input>
```

CSS:

```
// I tried this did not work
.slds-scope .slds-input[type=url]{
    height:48px;
}
// this one did not work too
.host{
    --slds-c-input-brand-min-height: 48px;
} 
// didn't work
.slds-scope .slds-input[type=url]{
    min-height:14rem;
}
```

Any inputs please?

Comment: what do you mean by the height?  it's a single line, so what will changing the height do? Or are you talking about the line height of the text within the input element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updates to Salesforce's CSS not working in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330471/updates-to-salesforces-css-not-working-in-lwc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't intend to use a [`lightning-textarea`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-textarea/example), the short answer is that you can't modify the height of a `lightning-input` base component.

Regular CSS won't work because of the Shadow DOM and there's no such [styling hook](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/?variant=base#Styling-Hooks-Overview) as `--slds-c-input-brand-min-height`.

What you could do if this is a critical business requirement is create your own copy of the input component based on [Lightning Design System HTML blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/) with some custom CSS.

Comment: I made it up '--slds-c-input-brand-min-height.' this stylehook. Thanks for correcting it